# Demo image not loaded from README.md

Tags: github

I have a very small project that I shared in github. I have a problem that demonstrative image is not displayed. The file is located on the same directory. I tried this:

```
[Glagolitic transliterator demo image](glagolicConverter.jpg?raw=true)
```

and this

```
[Glagolitic transliterator demo image](glagolicConverter.jpg)
```

and to add / before file name

```
[Glagolitic transliterator demo image](/glagolicConverter.jpg)
```

But unfortunately it did not help. This is project url: 
https://github.com/gonaumov/glagolicConverter

Thank you in advance for any help and advice.

Edit: 
I do change the question to share a lesson learned and to help peoples with similar problem in the future. Sometimes SO is much faster than reading documentation. Special thanks to user Nhor. If you want to embed image just 
use:

```
![Alt Text](url)
```

url can be relative also.

https://guides.github.com/features/mastering-markdown/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are only creating a link to your image. Try putting an exclamation mark before like this:

```
![Glagolitic transliterator demo image](/glagolicConverter.jpg)
```